# How to change colors of one bar in pandas stacked bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, stacked-chart

I want to change the color of one bar in a pandas stacked bar plot.  I want each section of this bar to be a different shade of orange.

This is the DataFrame that I am using to create my plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 
                  data={'age_13_to_17_results': [17.88321168, 17.44471744, 10.1511879 , 14.5979021 , 15.84756687,
                                                 15.18288475, 12.05357143], 
                        'age_18_to_24_results': [38.32116788, 25.55282555, 35.85313175, 32.77972028, 33.66902997, 
                                                 32.78541105, 28.79464286], 
                        'age_25_to_34_results': [24.45255474, 28.25552826, 26.99784017, 26.83566434, 27.87624879,
                                                 26.3713742 , 22.99107143], 
                        'age_35_to_44_results': [12.40875912, 11.3022113 , 16.41468683, 13.63636364, 12.72155978,
                                                 12.32616015, 15.625     ], 
                        'age_45_to_54_results': [5.10948905, 12.28501229,  6.47948164,  8.21678322,  6.69513374,
                                                 7.95114708, 12.72321429], 
                        'age_55_plus_results':  [1.82481752,  5.15970516,  4.10367171,  3.93356643,  3.22268772,
                                                 5.40393584,  7.8125]})
```

And this is the function for the bar plot:

```
def func(colors, A_colors):

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,13))
    ax = plt.subplot()
    plt.box(on=None)    
    height = 0.6

    df[::-1].plot.barh(stacked=True, edgecolor='black', width=height, color=colors, legend=False, ax=ax)

    for p in ax.patches[df.shape[1]::df.shape[0]]:
        p.set_facecolor(A_colors)
```

I am using a function named "lighten_color" to assign specific colors to each container in the bars.  This is what that function looks like:

```
def lighten_color(color, amount=0.5):
    import matplotlib.colors as mc
    import colorsys
    try:
        c = mc.cnames[color]
    except:
        c = color
    c = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*mc.to_rgb(c))
    return colorsys.hls_to_rgb(c[0], 1 - amount * (1 - c[1]), c[2])
```

To create the plot, I call the function:

```
func(colors=[lighten_color('#428bca', 1.4), 
             lighten_color('#428bca', 1.15), 
             lighten_color('#428bca', .9), 
             lighten_color('#428bca', .65), 
             lighten_color('#428bca', .4), 
             lighten_color('#428bca', .15)], 
     A_colors='orange')
```

and I get a plot that looks like this:

[image: stacked bar plot]

Instead of having the top bar all in one shade of orange, I would like to have each container in the top bar a different shade of orange similar to the bars below.  However, if I try to assign a list of colors to `A_colors` in the function, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: [(0.14703613676875715, 0.34955760816723397, 0.5243364122508509), (0.19899692108248268, 0.4730870199319398, 0.7096305298979095), (0.3329411764705885, 0.5905882352941176, 0.8129411764705881), (0.5182352941176473, 0.7043137254901961, 0.8649019607843136), (0.703529411764706, 0.8180392156862746, 0.9168627450980391), (0.8888235294117647, 0.9317647058823529, 0.9688235294117648)]
```

Does anyone know of a way to assign a different shade of orange to each individual container in the top bar?

Comment: You forgot to loop over the colors *as well as* the patches.